# xml file compare

Tags: c#, xml, compare

how to simply compare two xml files from element name.
if any element name is not matched it should return true, else false..
I am using

```
 var matches = from a in file1.Element("in_mind").Descendants()
                          join b in file2.Element("in_mind").Descendants() on a.Name equals b.Name
                          select new { First = a, Second = b };

            foreach (var n in matches)
                if(n.First.ToString().Intersect(n.Second.ToString()).Count()>0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("not matched");
                    return;
                }
```

but it is not checking the element name..

Comment: This is the fourth question about the same. What's wrong with previous answers?

Comment: i update the previous answers as posted above..but it is not giving the different values in "if" condition.I had comment one line in xml file but "if" loop doesnot break..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Get all descendant's names from both files and check if they are the same. I don't know if it is what you wanted to do.

```
var elements1=(from e in file1.Element("in_mind").Descendants() select e.Name).ToList();
var elements2=(from e in file2.Element("in_mind").Descendants() select e.Name).ToList();

for(int i=0;i<elements1.Count;i++)
{
    if(elements1[i]!=elements2[i])
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: it's not the best if you have many nodes but it can help you at first and you can optimize it later. Problem with join is that it doesn't ensure that the files are the same, only maybe that they have same elements somewhere. I think that exists the function for list comparing and it's more easier with that so you dont have to have for loop.